# WordPress Theme Developments - Start from another theme

Tags: theme-development, themes

Is it must to start WordPress theme development from beginning?

Can we edit a current theme and publish it as our work? What is law about that?

If it is possible, we can save lots of time. How to find those type of themes to edit?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the license in the theme so read carefully. [_S](http://underscores.me) and [Roots.io](https://roots.io/sage/) are good starter themes. Otherwise, a good place to look is [Google](http://google.com).